# What does my t-test error message mean when not enough "x" or "y" observations?

Tags: r

This question uses the data file at [https://people.ucsc.edu/~mclapham/eart125/data/rift_subsidence.csv](https://people.ucsc.edu/%7Emclapham/eart125/data/rift_subsidence.csv).

The passive margins formed by continental rifting can either have volcanic transitional crust or non-volcanic transitional crust. Does the rate of tectonic subsidence (measured in m/Myr) differ between the two types of rifted margins? Enter the t statistic below.

```
#Try1

rift_subsidence <- read.csv("https://people.ucsc.edu/~mclapham/eart125/data/rift_subsidence.csv")
View(rift_subsidence)

volcanic <- rift_subsidence$subsidence[rift_subsidence$margin_type == "Volcanic"]
non_volcanic <- rift_subsidence$subsidence[rift_subsidence$margin_type == "Non-volcanic"]
t.test(volcanic ~ non_volcanic, data = rift_subsidence)
```

> Result: Error in t.test.formula(volcanic ~ non_volcanic, data =
> rift_subsidence) :    grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels

```
#Try2

rift_subsidence <- read.csv("https://people.ucsc.edu/~mclapham/eart125/data/rift_subsidence.csv")
View(rift_subsidence)

volcanic <- rift_subsidence$subsidence[rift_subsidence$margin_type == "Volcanic"]
non_volcanic <- rift_subsidence$subsidence[rift_subsidence$margin_type == "Non-volcanic"]
t.test(volcanic, non_volcanic, paired=T)
```

```
Result: Error in t.test.default(volcanic, non_volcanic, paired = T) : 
  not enough 'x' observations
```

Hi Im new to coding and my professor said this in his email response to me but I cant troubleshoot it for some reason. Help please, thanks

> "[PROF] If you get error messages in the t test, most likely there is
> a problem with one or both of the objects you created as inputs. So,
> the first step is to look at the two input objects you created. You
> should look at each one to make sure it contains the data you expect.
>
> If you find that one (or both) of them has a problem, and doesn't
> contain the numbers you expect, you'll need to look at the code that
> produced the objects originally to find the problem there. You'll want
> to check the spelling of the column names and the spelling of the
> criterion (the target word) to make sure they are both correct.
> Everything needs to be exactly as written in the data.
>
> Each input will need to be a vector of numbers, which can be a column
> in a data frame object or an independent object on its own."

Comment: You don’t appear to have taken your Prof’s advice and looked at your data. You certainly haven’t shown us what you might have seen. To do a t-test with a formula, the format of the formula is `dependentVar ~ predictorVar`. You appear to have half your predictor variable on each side of your formula. So, start by mutating your data so that you have a *single* variable that indicates whether each row relates to volcanic or non-volcanic crust. Put your tectonic subsistence values in another column.

Comment: To perform a paired t-test, you would need to have paired data, which means that each observation in one group is paired with a corresponding observation in the other group. Based on the data you provided, it looks like you have two groups (volcanic
and non-volcanic) and the corresponding values for each group. However, the values within each group are not paired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two problems.

1. R compares strings in a *case-sensitive* way. The values in your `margin_type` variable are all lowercase:

```
table(rift_subsidence$margin_type)
non-volcanic     volcanic 
          21           13
```

but you extracted values based on the variable was equal to "Non-volcanic" or "Volcanic" — which won't match *any* rows of the data.

2. If you want to do a *paired* t-test, you're going to have trouble because there are unequal numbers of values in each category.

If you extract vectors correctly (case-sensitively) and use `paired = FALSE` you should get results (I haven't tested).

PS If you had looked at (i.e., printed) the `volcanic` or `non_volcanic` variables you created you would have seen `numeric(0)` — an **empty** numeric vector — which would have hinted that something went wrong with the extraction ...